# how to create given dataframe through given dataset in Spark with scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Dataset:

```
GroupID Name_of_books

101 book1, book2, book3, book4

102 book10, book12, book13, book14
```

---

Required output:

```
101 book1

101 book2

101 book3

101 book4

102 book10

102 book11

103 book12

104 book13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val resuldDF = df.select($"GroupID", explode($"Name_of_books").as("Name_of_books")
```

or withColumn

```
val resuldDF = df.withColumn("Name_of_books", explode($"Name_of_books"))
```

This works if the column is Array or Map
If you have a string value separated by a comma, You need to `split` it first and apply `explode` as

```
val resuldDF = df.select($"GroupID", explode(split($"Name_of_books", ",")))
```

Hope this helps!